# javascript timer keeps reseting too soon (not working)

Tags: javascript, timer

// This timer keeps reseting back to 2:00 after it reaches 1 minute. Also i do not get a notification that says times up at the right time. Can someone please correct the code. Also the stop/resume timer button also has to stay functional.

```js
var isRunning = false;
var ticker; //this will hold our setTimeout
var seconds,
  minutes;

function countdown(mins, secs) {
  //i made these global, so we can restart the timer later
  seconds = secs || 60; //if user put in a number of minutes, use that. Otherwise, use 60
  minutes = mins;
 console.log('time stuff',mins,secs,minutes,seconds)
  function tick() {
    var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
    var current_minutes = mins - 1
    seconds--;
    counter.innerHTML =
      current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
    if (seconds < 1 && minutes) {
   //seconds reached 0, and still minutes left;
      seconds=60;
      minutes--;
    }
    if ((seconds > 0 || minutes > 0) && isRunning) {
      ticker = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    } else if(isRunning){
     console.log(seconds,minutes,isRunning)
      alert('Time\'s up, brah!')
    }
  }
  tick();
}

function timeToggle() {
 isRunning = !isRunning; //if it's false, set it true. If it's true, set it false.
  if (!isRunning) {
    clearTimeout(ticker); //or whatever else you set the initial timeOut to.
  } else {
    //not running! and time is defined;
    var sec = seconds||60;
    console.log('def!',minutes, sec)
    countdown(minutes, sec);
    
  } 
  
}
isRunning = true;
countdown(2);
```

```html
<div id="timer">2:00</div>
<button onclick="timeToggle()">Stop time</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small flaw in your logic.

During the countdown initialization your doing

```
seconds = secs || 60;
```

Which effectively add 60 seconds to the time you want if you don't initialize the seconds. see:

```
function countdownInit(mins, secs) {
  seconds = secs || 60;
  minutes = mins;
  console.log(mins + 'min ' + seconds + 'sec');
}

countdownInit(1, 30) // ok
// 1min 30sec

countdownInit(1) // not ok
// 1min 60sec
// thats 2 minutes
```

The second issue here is that you use a var `current_minutes` that equals `minutes - 1` to display the time. So you are not showing the real counter.

the fix is as follow:

```
function countdown(mins, secs) {
    seconds = secs;
    minutes = mins;
    // if secs is 0 or uninitialized we set seconds to 60 and decrement the minutes
    if(!secs) {
      minutes--;
      seconds = 60;
    }

    function tick() {
        var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
        seconds--;
        // we use minutes instead of current_minutes in order to show what's really in our variables
        counter.innerHTML =
          minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);

        // rest of code
    }
    // rest of code
}
```

I tried to keep as much as your code as possible.